# I need a word that is suggests both positively and negatively, good and bad. Almost like bittersweet

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

This is for a medical essay. It's both good that we have this example, as it lets us learn about the condition, but also bad, because it exists at all.

It's to begin a sentence. For example, instead of using interestingly, as i believe it's insensitive.

"Interestingly, we can see this example in humans too."

I saw in other feeds people suggested agathokakological, however i don't want to make my markers have to look up a word. Never goes down well.

Thank you for your help!!!!! :)

Comment: Do we also get some credit in your paper for helping you out?

Comment: +1 for avoiding abstruse language. But I think you're muddying the simple core idea of your sentence (we see this thing in humans too) with a complicated idea that we wish we did not see it in humans because it's not a good thing, but it's good that we can see it because we can study it.

Comment: @Neptunian if you get the right words, who knows!

Comment: @TimRomano Yes, thanks, i understand what you're saying. I think unless i find the perfect word, i'll stick with what I've got, but I just wanted to show some sensitivity.

Comment: "Unfortunately".

Comment: It's an every-cloud-has-a-silver-lining sort of thing.

Comment: "Interesting" is an unnecessary value judgement—as would be other words like "sadly" and so on. Really, a scientific work is better off without any of this sort of thing. Just state the facts: "This phenomenon is observed in humans too."

Comment: Or you can begin with "fascinatingly" and then continue with "deplorably."

Comment: *Interestingly*, I notice that [Prof Robert Sapolsky](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL848F2368C90DDC3D) repeatedly describes some pretty appalling conditions as "interesting" or "cool". I'm pretty sure at one point in that series of lectures I'm working through, he uses some such term in reference to a brain disorder whereby your body loses the ability to breath automatically. He asks the students what they think will happen to such a person. They guess suffocation/asphyxia; almost gleefully, he points out they die from sleep deprivation. ***That's** interesting!*, as he always says.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you dance around it. Shakespeare did with his "sweet sorrow."

Instead of looking for obscure Latinate words, you might as well say what you said just now:

It is tragic, or at least very unpleasant, that humans can contract it as well. But since that's the case, and since we have to tackle it anyway, we might as well admit that certain aspects of it are fascinating; and, while hoping that our efforts will prove useful to humanity sooner or later, we might as well have some fun studying it.

Comment: You forgot to add "So, if you're suffering from moderate to severe X, remember to leave your name and contact information on the sheet of paper by the door."

Comment: @TimRomano  We're talking about an essay, not a lecture. If the OP had a lecture in mind, I would have certainly suggested it, and probably thrown something in about considerable discounts for the first three or four trial groups.

Answer (score 0):

[**ambivalently:**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ambivalently)

> having mixed feelings about someone or something; being unable to choose between two (usually opposing) courses of action:

*'Ambivalently, we can see this example in humans too.'*